# Robocopy /mov logs all files from target folder?

Tags: windows, logging, robocopy

I use robocopy in order to move files from the source to the target folder. That works well, I'm a bit surprised about the logging of robocopy - it lists all files of the target folder?

Lets say we have two folders, an empty source folder and a target folder with some files (target1-3). If I run this command:

```
robocopy "D:\test\source" "D:\test\target" /S /MOV /R:10 /W:30 /UNILOG+:"log.txt"
```

I got this output (sorry für the german):

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robustes Dateikopieren fr Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Gestartet: Dienstag, 6. April 2021 20:50:24
   Quelle : D:\test\source\
     Ziel : D:\test\target\

    Dateien : *.*
        
  Optionen: *.* /S /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /MOV /R:10 /W:30 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                       0    D:\test\source\
      *EXTRA Datei             0    target1.txt
      *EXTRA Datei             0    target2.txt
      *EXTRA Datei             0    target3.txt

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

           Insgesamt   KopiertšbersprungenKeine šbereinstimmung    FEHLER    Extras
Verzeich.:         1         0         1         0         0         0
  Dateien:         0         0         0         0         0         3
    Bytes:         0         0         0         0         0         0
   Zeiten:   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
   Beendet: Dienstag, 6. April 2021 20:50:24
```

Why does robocopy list all files from the target folder? How could I avoid that? (This list could become long in the real use case.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use additional switches to reduce the logging. I recommend having a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy#logging-options) of `robocopy`. You can add the `/NFL` option to omit the logging of files. And you can add the `/NDL` option to omit the logging of directories:

```
robocopy "D:\test\source" "D:\test\target" /S /MOV /R:10 /W:30 /NFL /NDL /UNILOG+:"log.txt"
```

But this will omit the logging of all files and directories (not only the `EXTRA` ones). If you just do not want to have `EXTRA` files and directories in your log, but everything else, you need additional tools. You can post process your log file (if it is worth it):

```
(Select-String -Path log.txt -Pattern '^\s+\*EXTRA' -NotMatch | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line) | Set-Content -Path log.txt
```

This PowerShell pipeline will remove every line from `log.txt`, that starts with spaces, followed by `*EXTRA`.

FYI: `robocopy` logs `EXTRA` files, because it cannot only be used for copying, but also for a unidirectional synchronization. So you cannot only copy files to a destination, but also delete files at a destination, that do not exist (anymore) at the source location. Have a look at the `/PURGE` and `/MIR` options.

Comment: Ok, so robocopy doesn't make a difference in logging depending on the requested action. Then it remains with the additional entries in the log.

Comment: Basically, the action is always a unidirectional synchronization, you just decide if you want to *keep* extra files or not. You can even sync an empty source to a destination while using the `/PURGE` option. This will make `robocopy` look like a delete operation. So the word "copy" in "robocopy" might somehow be misleading.